# GWT - XML parser - cannot read tag

Tags: xml, gwt

I just faced a problem with gwt xml parser

the thing is ...

I have xml like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<A>
<B>
<C>C1</C>
<C>C2</C>
<C>C3</C>
</B>
<B></B>
</A>
<A>
</A>
```

and gwt code...

```
Document document = XMLParser.parse(xml);
NodeList nl= document.getElementsByTagName("A");
Window.alert("threads length = "+nl.getLength());
```

for some reason nl.getLength() returns 0 that means there is no A tag :( Why that may happen and how to get xml structure correctly?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Comment: Strictly speaking, an XML document can only contain *one* top-level (or "root") element node. That has two. This is not an answer, however, because I am ensure how `XMLParser` will treat somewhat-invalid markup :)

Comment: +1 @pst ... Oh :) Thank you. That was the problem I guess. I removed additional tag pair and all worked :)

Comment: Apart from noting that the input isn't well-formed XML, the other relevant factor is that (I believe) GWT's XMLParser is actually a wrapper around the XML parser provided by the browser's Javascript XML parser implementation. So it might be relevant to know which browser you were using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to close this question...

Strictly speaking, an XML document can only contain one top-level (or "root") element node. That has two.

`XMLParser` will apparently "not work correctly" for this malformed XML input <-- please feel free to add details here or in a comment :)

Happy coding.